# Securing/sanitizing remote calls to server by untrusted clients

Tags: python, rest, api, protocol-buffers, rpc

I'm building an API which will expose (among other things) the following calls:

1. Upload file to remote server.
2. Perform various computations (over some set of possible function) on remotely uploaded file.

I'm trying to do this on Python. What are the best practices when the client is untrusted, meaning that they can upload arbitrarily crafted files?
What's the standard procedure nowadays? RPC, REST, something else?

I do not need to worry about authentication and/or encryption, requests can be anonymous and in the clear. MITM is not a concern either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat any client as untrusted, so your case will need a general approach which can be found at [OWASP ASVS](https://www.owasp.org/images/3/33/OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_3.0.1.pdf) (v16: files and resources verification requirements). REST is OK for this purpose.

The main points are:

- store files outside of webroot (e.g. it can't be served by static page server)
- avoid setting the execution bit on (for Linux)
- if it is possible, limit file types to know-good ones (e.g. validation against whitelist; validate filetypes by extension **AND** by [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures))
- check that files do have an appropriate size **before** accepting requests and putting files into variables (you can check it by HTTP content-length and filter it before passing to an app)
- if it is possible, check files with server antivirus
- if files are served back to a user, ensure that the appropriate headers (content-type, no-sniff) are set. If they are not, some XSS scenarios are possible
- verify that filenames are sanitized so they won't trick you program into serving other files (e.g. there might be a scenario where filename "../../../../../../etc/passwd" will serve an actual /etc/passwd file). Reject request if filename contains ../ or / sequences.
- do not ever concatenate path to folders with filenames because it can give the same issue
- if computations will be made via calling the command line, beware of command line injections (this issue and 2 previous can be solved by specifying the file name format to the users, e.g. accept only alphanumeric names without spaces or any special chars and reject any request that won't fit the pattern)
- if you can, limit requests number by IP

Comment: This was a fantastic answer. Thank you, this is exactly the baseline I needed.